# JMockit creating a fake FacesContext ResourceBundle

Tags: java, jsf, mocking, jmockit

Previously I have been using `@Mocked` on a `ResourceBundle` eg.

```
@Test
public void testMyMethod(@Mocked final ResourceBundle resourceBundle) {
    new Expectations() {
        {
            resourceBundle.getString("someString");
            result = "myResult";
        }
    }
}
```

This has worked fine until a particular method I'm testing has the following line of code

```
DateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
```

If I created a mock `ResourceBundle` using the method above then my test would throw a `NumberFormatException` on this line, reason being the `SimpleDateFormat` constructor does some work with a `ResourceBundle` whilst building a `Calendar` instance for its default `Locale`.

So what I wish to do is to create a fake that will return my mocked result for some calls to `getString` and the default for others eg.

```
new Mockup<ResourceBundle>() {
    @Mock
    public String getString(Invocation inv, String key) {
        if ("someString".equals(key)) {
            return "myResult";
        } else if ("someOtherString".equals(key)) {
            return "myOtherResult";
        } else {
            return inv.proceed();
        }
    }
};
```

I wish to use this fake `ResourceBundle` when it is retrieved via a `FacesContext` eg.

```
FacesContext facesContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
ResourceBundle bundle = facesContext.getApplication().getResourceBundle(facesContext, "myBundle");
```

As my test isn't running inside a running container I am mocking the `FacesContext` and I'd like to use the fake I've created, so I have something like this

```
@Test
public void testMyMethod(@Mocked final FacesContext facesContext) {
    final ResourceBundle resourceBundle = new Mockup<ResourceBundle>() {
        @Mock
        public String getString(Invocation inv, String key) {
            if ("someString".equals(key)) {
                return "myResult";
            } else if ("someOtherString".equals(key)) {
                return "myOtherResult";
            } else {
                return inv.proceed();
            }
        }
    }.getMockInstance();

    new Expectations() {
    {
        facesContext.getApplication().getResourceBundle(facesContext, "myBundle");
        result = resourceBundle; 
    }

    unitUnderTest.methodUnderTest();
}
```

However it looks like it's using the default `ResourceBundle getString()` for all cases and not using my fake

Comment: Are you sure that mocked resourceBundle is use in your ApplicationContext or CDI context ? You have to put in the context to replace standard implementation.

Comment: `@Mocked` should mock ALL instances of the FacesContext so not entirely sure what you mean?

Comment: Make a check in you test, if you said that getString() call the default implementation it's because the default implementation is used in the context, even if it will be the mocked implementation.

Comment: Remove the mock-up and add an `@Injectable ResourceBundle` mock parameter; keep the `@Mocked FacesContext` and replace the expectation block with the first from the question. It should work and the test will be much shorter.

Answer (score 0):

OK so I managed to find a solution that does what I want, the key to getting this working was to use `Deencapsulation.invoke` on the `FacesContext.setCurrentInstance()`

```
@Test
public void testMyMethod() {
    final FacesContext facesContext = new Mockup<FacesContext>() {
        @Mock
        public Application getApplication() {
            return new MockUp<Application>() {
                @Mock
                public ResourceBundle getResourceBundle(FacesContext ctx, String name) {
                    return new MockUp<ResourceBundle>() {
                        @Mock
                        public String getString(Invocation inv, String key) {
                            if ("someString".equals(key)) {
                                return "myResult";
                            } else if ("someOtherString".equals(key)) {
                                return "myOtherResult";
                            } else {
                                return inv.proceed();
                            }
                        }    
                    }.getMockInstance();
                }
            }.getMockInstance();
        }
    }.getMockInstance();

    Deencapsulation.invoke(FacesContext.class, "setCurrentInstance", facesContext);

    unitUnderTest.methodUnderTest();
}
```